# How do I run a Python script in .ebextensions?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My `.ebextensions/00.commands.config` looks like:

```
container_commands:
  00_download_models:
    command: "./download.py"
```

My `download.py` has:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

print('now')
```

But in `/var/log/cfn-init.log`, I have:

```
2020-06-25 17:19:34,933 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2020-06-25 17:19:34,933 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command 00_download_models failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 171, in <module>
    worklog.build(metadata, configSets)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 129, in build
    Contractor(metadata).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 530, in build
    self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 542, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 260, in build
    changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 117, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
ToolError: Command 00_download_models failed
```

Seems pretty straight forward, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you try changing it to `command: "./download.py"` or `command: "python3 download.py"`?

Comment: Same issue with `command: "./download.py"`

Comment: Try specifying the full path to `download.py`. How is download.py getting installed? Are you using a files resource in cfn-init?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **nothing wrong** with your script and technique, based on what you described.

I **verified it** using my own EB Environment (64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.0.3 running Python 3.7; single instance).

To confirm, I used the following :

**.ebextensions/50_commands.config**

```
container_commands:
  00_download_models:
    command: "./download.py"
```

**./download.py** was located in the root of my zip package (not in `.ebextensions` folder):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# easier to find the /tmp/test.txt file then search though logs for "now"
with open('/tmp/test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('from python script')
```

Also I made sure that `./download.py` has **execution permissions** before creating EB environment by executing the following on my local workstation:

```
chmod +x ./download.py
```

My `download.py` is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import datetime
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
from transformers import (
    CTRLLMHeadModel,
    CTRLTokenizer,
    GPT2LMHeadModel,
    GPT2Tokenizer,
    TransfoXLLMHeadModel,
    TransfoXLTokenizer,
    XLMTokenizer,
    XLMWithLMHeadModel,
    XLNetLMHeadModel,
    XLNetTokenizer,
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open('/tmp/test.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('Starting download', datetime.datetime.now().time(), '\n')
        GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained('distilgpt2')
        f.write('DistilModel', datetime.datetime.now().time(), '\n')
        GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained('gpt2-xl')
        f.write('GPT2-XL', datetime.datetime.now().time(), '\n')
        GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained('gpt2-medium')
        f.write('GPT2-medium', datetime.datetime.now().time(), '\n')
        CTRLLMHeadModel.from_pretrained('ctrl')
        f.write('CTRL', datetime.datetime.now().time(), '\n')

        GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('distilgpt2'),
        GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2-xl'),
        GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2-medium'),
        CTRLTokenizer.from_pretrained('ctrl')

        f.write('Finished download\n')
```

Comment: Looks like I didn't do the `chmod` step. Thanks!

Comment: Actually - it seems to also fail if the work in `download.py` is large.

Comment: @Shamoon Do you have an example of the "large" download.py? I can also try to replicate that issue on my EB env.

Comment: Updated with the contents

Comment: @Shamoon `torch` is the only thing I need to install as a pre-requisit to attempt to run it?